# How to output a VBScript to a text file

Tags: vbscript, output

My original problem was that I wanted to output a VBScript to a text file. It was at first doing an echo, and printing a blank file. I only wanted it to print, and to print the data.

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Processor")

For Each objItem in colItems
Dim fso, MyFile
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set MyFile = fso.CreateTextFile("c:\Users\Tyler\Desktop\dude.txt", True)
MyFile.WriteLine("Name: " & objItem.Name)
MyFile.Close
Next
```

This is the correct code. I also wanted to get more than one device printed to file. In the example below, I have the CPU name+frequency read and printed then the GPU information read and printed to the **same** text file.

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Processor")

For Each objItem in colItems
Dim fso, MyFile
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set MyFile = fso.CreateTextFile("c:\Users\Tyler\Desktop\dude.txt", True)
MyFile.WriteLine("Name: " & objItem.Name)

Next

strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_VideoController")

For Each objItem in colItems
    MyFile.WriteLine ("Driver Version: " & objItem.DriverVersion)
    MyFile.WriteLine ("Name: " & objItem.Name)
    MyFile.WriteLine ("Video Processor: " & objItem.VideoProcessor)
Next

    MyFile.Close
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost had it my friend

```
On Error Resume Next

strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
& "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set objFSO=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Processor")

outFile="C:\Users\Tyler\Desktop\test.txt"

Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(outFile,True)

For Each objItem in colItems
  objFile.WriteLine "Name: " & objItem.Name
Next

objFile.Close
```

Comment: Awesome! Let's say I wanted to combine two and write to one file. How would I do that? You can take this same file and do it twice.

Comment: You want to write info for two computers into one file?

Comment: Sorry, I meant I would like to write multiple device infos to one file. For example, I would like it to read and write the CPU information as well as the display adapter. I ended up going a different route before I got your answer. Check the original post for updated code.

Comment: Scratch that! I figured it out. I will update original post with solutions for others to find.